# jQuery resizable document.getElementFromPoint FF returns wrong value

Tags: jquery

First things first: I have asked this question a couple of years ago but figured out now that it is not working in FF :-(

[Earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500422/jquery-resizable-get-first-td-value-at-stop-event)

I have a `resizable div` in a table and want to find out the `id` of the first `td` where I stop resizing the `div`

Please see the snippet below and the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/140316/) as the snippet is not working properly.

Everything is working fine in Chrome.

To get the element below the resized div I use

```
var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

and to get the time (the id of the first `td`) I call

```
var time = $('td:first', $(elem).parents('tr')).attr('id');
```

Chrome returns the right `id` (see JSFiddle)

Firefox is returning also an `id` but always the `id` of the `td` where I started resizing.

So when I resize the `div` from 08:00 to 09:00 Chrome returns ***32400*** which is correct.

Firefox returns ***28800*** which is not correct!!

(And I know an `id` should always start with an alphanumeric character ;-))

Thanks for you help! I really appreciate it!

```js
$("#test").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).resizable({
   grid:45,
    autoHide: true,
    start: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).data('origHeight', ui.originalSize.height);
    },
    resize: function(event, ui) {
      ui.size.width = ui.originalSize.width;
      $(this).css({
        lineHeight: ui.size.height + 'px',
        zIndex: 8000
      });
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var y = ($(this).offset().top + ui.size.height);
      var x = $(this).offset().left;
      var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
      var time = $('td:first', $(elem).parents('tr')).attr('id');
      console.log($(elem));
      console.log(time);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.dragDiv {
  background-color: #14A07D;
  background: linear-gradient(#1BD6A7, #14A07D);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: pre;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.dragDiv:hover {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  background: #ff0080;
  background: linear-gradient(#fe78ad, #ff0080);
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #f0f0ec;
  border-top: 1px dashed #f0f0ec;
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e4;
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e4;
  *height: 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table name="kalender" width="100%" border="0">

  <tr height="45px">
    <td id="28800"><b>08:00</b></td>
    <td>1
      <div class="dragDiv" style="height:44px; line-height:44px; font-size:12px;" id="test">TEST</div>
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="45px">
    <td id="30600">08:30</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="45px">
    <td id="32400"><b>09:00</b></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="45px">
    <td id="34200">09:30</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved.

```
var elem = document.elementFromPoint(Math.round(x), y)
```

Rounding the value of `x` solved it. Don't know why but it works